# how to filter the resulted table in dbeaver?

Tags: sqlite, dbeaver

I have big sqlite table that I filtered one column with `IN` statement from the GUI. It worked will but I want to filter another second column also based on the first selected. eg full table looks like.

```
A    v
A    c
A    n
B    o
B    i
B    k
C    l
C    a
C    z
```

after first query

```
A    v
A    c
A    n
C    l
C    a
C    z
```

I want to filter this second column only (without the o, i, k available in selection menu). 
I found the  best solution is the `CREATE TABLE`, name it, then use it.

However, I don't know where this table is saved. I can't find it in the explorer however it is there when I `SELECT` it.

What would you do if you have to do that?

Comment: Just remove unwanted character from IN clause.Why do you want to create another table with filtered column?

Comment: I want to filter another column but I want those only items present in the first selected column. For example if the first column is persons name, I want to filter next filter those person based on their job title. dbeaver only allow to use GUI for one column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter on multiple columns with DBeaver, either on tables or query results.

The menu is called "Custom filter" and is located at the top right of the query result:

[image]

From there you can specify custom filters as you need:

[image]

Comment: The DBeaver developers have mental issues